# AWS free tier usage

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jvm

I am using AWS t2.medium instance which is a paid intance.
Right now i have all the three servers in one instance :

```
SQL
Tomcat
Apache
```

And i am using 4 GB Ram instance.
Now i want to use  AWS free tier instances which has 1 GB Ram.
I will have a separate free tier intance for each of my servers.
I want to check whether my free tier instance would be capable of handling my Tomcat alone.

DATA for tomcat memory usage. :

```
VIRT = 3620m
RES = 507m
SHR = 11m
Mem = 12.8%
```

So which utilization should i be concerned.
Is the real usage of tomcat is  resident memory or since virtual utilization is more than 1 GB i would not be able to use tomcat in a free tier instance?

Comment: What are the used heap settings for the tomcat server? BTW.: The free tier includes a max. number of hours (750 a month for a micro instance). You may switch one of the servers to a free micro instance and set the other to a small instance to save money. You concept works only if the instances run only a third of the month.

Comment: JAVA_OPTS=" -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"  are my heap settinngs. Yes i got your point of 750 hours free tier. So there are three 3 configs which i can go with:

Comment: 1. I can have apache and SQL in 1 free tier instance and use another free tier instance for tomcat : this will have minimum cost implication but for this i need to be sure whether my tomcat would be able to run comfortably in 1GB ram .

Comment: 2 . I can have apache and sql in one free tier instance and use t2.small instance having 2 GB Ram for my tomcat: only t2.small intance charge would be implied . 3. Using t2.medium instance which i am using now and use seperate free tier instance for my testing.

Comment: So which config would you recommend?

Comment: I would use a reserved instance t2.medium if you are sure to keep the environment for a year. A second account with free tier may be used for testing. Using different accounts for each instance may increase the setup configuration effort.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for EC2 provides:

> - 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage (1 GiB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month*
> - 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Microsoft Windows Server† t2.micro instance usage (1 GiB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month
> - 750 hours of an Elastic Load Balancer plus 15 GB data processing*
> - 30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage in any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic, plus 2 million I/Os (with EBS Magnetic) and 1 GB of snapshot storage*
>
> * These free tier offers are only available to new AWS customers, and are available for 12 months following your AWS sign-up date. When your 12 month free usage term expires or if your application use exceeds the tiers, you simply pay standard, pay-as-you-go service rates (see each service page for full pricing details).

Therefore, you can only run 1 x Linux and 1 x Windows server continuously for free, and only in your first 12 months of service.

Therefore, it will not be possible to "have a separate free tier instance for each of my servers".

As to what to run... it's a tradeoff between meeting the needs of your application and your users vs reducing costs.

Some cost-saving options:

- **[Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html)** can be used to scale-out your infrastructure when needed and scale-in when it is not needed.
- **[Spot pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/)** can be used to obtain instances up to 90% off, but with the risk that they will be removed if the spot price rises above your bid price.